# Получение адреса экземпляра класса внутри самого класса

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, this

Есть класс `Point`. В `main` создается, допустим, 5 экземпляров: `pnt1 - pnt5`. Между ними создается список связей - некоторые экземпляры соединяются с некоторыми другими. Это описано в массиве `std::vector<connect> connects`, где `connect` - структура из двух указателей на соединенные экземпляры `Point`. Внутри класса `Point` есть массив `std::vector<Point*> connects;`, который нужно заполнить указателями на экземпляры, с которыми связан непосредственно конкретный экземпляр.

Код `main`:

```
int main() {

    Point pnt1 = Point();
    Point pnt2 = Point();
    Point pnt3 = Point();
    Point pnt4 = Point();
    Point pnt5 = Point();

    std::vector<Point::connect> connect_list;
    // pnt2 связан с pnt1, pnt2 и  pnt4
    connect_list.push_back({ &pnt1, &pnt2 });
    connect_list.push_back({ &pnt2, &pnt3 });
    connect_list.push_back({ &pnt2, &pnt4 });
    ... // другие соединения

    // теперь отфильтруем информацию для pnt2, вот тут работает неправильно
    pnt2.setConnects(connect_list, &pnt2);
...
}
```

При использовании `this` внутри экземпляра программа работала неправильно, поэтому в функцию подал явный адрес экземпляра `&pnt2`.

Код класса `Point`:

```
class Point
{
private:
    std::vector<Point*> connects;
public:
    struct connect{ Point* pnt1; Point* pnt2; };

    void setConnects(std::vector<connect> given_connects, Point* this_adr){
        for (int i = 0; i < connects.size(); i++) {
            // используем поданный указатель и указатель this для сравнения
            // если в структуре первый элемент это наш экземпляр, то второй элемент - связанный с ним
            if (given_connects[i].pnt1 == this_adr) {
                connects.push_back(given_connects[i].pnt2);
            }
            // или наоборот
            if (given_connects[i].pnt2 == this) {
                connects.push_back(given_connects[i].pnt1);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

С помощью точек остановки, при вызове функции, увидел значения указателей: `this_adr == 0x00f0f994; this == 0x00f0f648`, то есть они указывают на разные объекты.

Почему `this` работает неправильно. Это получается, указатель на класс в целом, а не на текущий элемент? Как мне получить действующий указатель, чтобы не передавать `this_adr` в функцию каждый раз?

Comment: Добавьте [mcve], пожалуйста.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, в main копировал не тот вектор, исправил

Comment: *"Не верю" (С)таниславский :)* Выдрав минимальный пример из вашего кода, видим это - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a72f74267008fce7

Comment: @Harry, все, совсем заработался, мой косяк - в цикле неправильный размер поданного массива (размер структуры). Пойду отдыхать, чтобы меньше таких глупых вопросов после задавать :)